# Google Drive Api Not working, its always showing an error as javascript origin mismatch

Tags: php, google-drive-api, cfc

i tried to solve

> 400. That’s an error.
>        Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>        The JavaScript origin in the request, http://site-name.com

But couldn't solved this issue can anybody please tell me solution about this.
[image]

Here is my setting 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to use a URL that has an SSL certificate. Many web service REST APIs now require return URLs to use the 'https' protocol.

Comment: I am wondering whether it is because you are not using a subdomain, like 'www'?